# End of the study date in survival analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model

I'm looking for the time from the first event to the second event in one year from the first event.
If the individual has the second event after one year from the first event or didn't have the second event then the individual will be censored. So, each individual will have a different end study date.

Does it correct to do survival analysis even the end study date for each individual is different?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I understood: technically, the 'relative' study end, i.e. the end of the study period starting at the first event is fixed, i.e. you always censor after the first year after the first event. So technically, we could consider all the subjects to have their first event at 'relative time 0' and then you have a fixed length of the study again. However, this will only work well if the time the patients had before the first event is independent to what happens between the first and the second event...

Comment: I.e. I could imagine that in the scenario first event = heart stroke, second event = death will produce fairly confusing results using this approach: if a person is already old and the body is 'weak' then the chance of dying after a heart stroke is bigger than for a young person, so the 'one year after the first event' period for old people is unfairly long in comparison to the year after the heart stroke for young people...

Comment: Thank you Fabian Werner for your comments. If the first event is the first infection and the second event is the second infection. So, one year after the first infection for each patient. Do you think the survival analysis will be ok ?

Comment: I think you should at least take care of one more factor that could influence the analysis. For example: When you test a new medicine then you need to make sure that the groups you hand the new/old medicine to are 'equal', i.e. do take only females as test group and only males as control group because then gender might cause effects that mislead you to believe to be effects of the new/old medicine. In that sense you need to make sure that 'age when the first infection happened' is also 'equally' distributed along the test and control group.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Do you have any reference could discuss this idea that the end of study is fixed from the first event for each individual because each individual will have a different date for the end of study ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have an 'official' source at hand for this...

Comment: For starting off: Just check by eye that the histograms for 'age' of test and control group do not look 'too different' from each other. If they do then I cannot imagine anything else than deleting selected people from test/control that make these histograms different. Depending on your setup that may be impossible (lack of data?). Then you must figure out and implement the relationship between age and 'ad hoc' survival time into the model so that you only get an answer like 'long' when the sruvival time is 'exceptionally long for the age of the subject' or so.